# Reading first non-list value from the arbitrary nested list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

How to write a function which needs to access the first value which is not a list from an arbitray-deep nested list? Sometimes right syntax will be `somelist[0]`, some other time `somelist[0][0]` etc. Is flattening of the whole list just to read the first one correct solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like

```
value = my_list[0]
if isinstance(value, list):
    value = value[0]

# use the value
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python).

Summarizing:

```
from itertools import chain
myList = [ [1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [], [114, 66, 55] ]
flatList = list( chain( *myList ) )
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 114, 66, 55]`

Then just access `flatList[0]` for the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_first_item(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return get_first_item(value[0])
    return value
```